# Has anybody used alternative hyperparameter optimization techniques (other than default one) in SK-Learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameter, hyperparameter-tuning, gaussian-process

I've been using Sklearn for Gaussian process regression that has L-BFGS-B (`“fmin_l_bfgs_b”`) as a default optimization algorithm. I want to implement some other internally available algorithms like  [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html#scipy.optimize.least_squares) and some other third party algorithm like [Firefly algorithm](https://github.com/7ossam81/EvoloPy).

I tried to use the  `trust-region-reflective algorithm` with the following way:

```
def nll_fn(X_train, Y_train, noise):
    ''' Returns a function that computes the negative log-likelihood for training data X_train and Y_train and given noise level. Args: X_train: training locations (m x d). Y_train: training targets (m x 1). noise: known noise level of Y_train. Returns: Minimization objective. '''
    def step(theta):
        K = kernel(X_train, X_train, l=theta[0], sigma_f=theta[1]) + noise**2 * np.eye(len(X_train))
        # Compute determinant via Cholesky decomposition
        return np.sum(np.log(np.diagonal(cholesky(K)))) + 0.5 * Y_train.T.dot(inv(K).dot(Y_train)) + 0.5 * len(X_train) * np.log(2*np.pi)
    return step

def trust_region_optimizer(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds):
    trust_region_method = least_squares(obj_func,initial_theta,bounds,method='trf')
    return (trust_region_method.x,trust_region_method.fun)
```

However, I get the error as:

```
trust_region_method = least_squares(obj_func,initial_theta,bounds,method='trf')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_lsq\least_squares.py", line 744, in least_squares
    raise ValueError("`jac` must be '2-point', '3-point', 'cs' or "
ValueError: `jac` must be '2-point', '3-point', 'cs' or callable.
```

Has anybody implemented any other optimization algorithm in Sklearn? Any sample code or tutorial links would be very much helpful. Moreover, any sample codes for optimization algorithms in any platform (E.g. Matlab) would be very supportive.

Thank you.

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward: you're passing to `least_squares` the variable `bounds` into the third argument slot, which is supposed to be `jac`.  
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html  
Just use `bounds=bounds` to specify the keyword argument.

Comment: @BenReiniger Updated code`def trust_region_optimizer(obj_func, initial_theta, bounds): trust_region_method = least_squares(obj_func, x0_rosenbrock, jac='2-point', bounds=bounds, method='trf', ftol=1e-08, xtol=1e-08, gtol=1e-08, x_scale=1.0, loss='linear', f_scale=1.0, diff_step=None, tr_solver=None, tr_options={}, jac_sparsity=None, max_nfev=None, verbose=0, args=(), kwargs={})
    return (trust_region_method.x,trust_region_method.fun)` 
where `x0_rosenbrock = np.array([2, 2])`.

Comment: @BenReiniger New error:
`K = kernel(X_train, X_train, l=theta[0], sigma_f=theta[1]) + noise**2 * np.eye(len(X_train))
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'l'`

Comment: @BenReiniger `gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel ,optimizer = trust_region_optimizer(nll_fn(x_train, y_train, 0.001), 0, (1e-5, 1e5)), alpha =1.2, n_restarts_optimizer=10)` where the the used kernel is RBF kernel.